# How to pass another Series to pandas.Series.str.startswith

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame with two columns: uid, and name:

```
In[1]: import pandas as pd

In[2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['123', 'OneTwoThree'],
                          ['456', '456 FourFiveSix'],
                          ['789', 'SevenEightNine']],
                         columns = ['uid', 'name'])
In[3]: df
Out[3]:
   uid             name
0  123      OneTwoThree
1  456  456 FourFiveSix
2  789   SevenEightNine
```

I want to select rows where the name starts with the uid. I can do this with a list comprehension:

```
In[4]: df[[name.startswith(uid) for uid, name in zip(df.uid, df.name)]]
Out[4]:
   uid             name
1  456  456 FourFiveSix
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this using pandas.Series.str.startswith, e.g. something like:

```
df[df.name.str.startswith(df.uid)]
```

Comment: There's a relevant [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3485) discussing this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether is more elegant, but it's an alternative:

```
sw = lambda x: x["uid"] in x["name"]
df[df.apply(sw, axis=1)]
```

Or in one line:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x["uid"] in x["name"], axis=1)]
```

And if `startswith` is a requirement:

```
sw2 = lambda x: x["name"].startswith(x["uid"])
df[df.apply(sw2, axis=1)]
```

It turns out that the lambda version are slower than yours (on your dataset at least), so if speed matters, this is a bit faster than yours, but your dataframe needs to contain only the 2 columns:

```
df[[name.startswith(uid) for uid, name in df.values]]
```